# Undocumented Hotspot OpenJDK System properties

Tags: java, java.util.logging, system-properties, openjdk-11

I've recently discovered some undocumented system properties in the JDK's [System.Logger API](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/264), in particular, `jdk.logger.finder.singleton`. I couldn't find any web pages which mention this system property or any property at all relating to the System.Logger API. Nor is it mentioned in the [System.LoggerFinder javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/System.LoggerFinder.html).

The lack of information on these properties raises several questions:

- Is it acceptable, supported, or intended for application developers to use these properties?
- Why do the JDK developers leave undocumented properties in the openjdk implementation?

It reminds me of the [file.encoding](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8187041) property, which I read is not a "supported mechanism."

Answer (score 3):

> Is it acceptable, supported, or intended for application developers to use these properties?

No, unless it's properly documented in public API, developers shouldn't use it. Different JVM/JRE implementation will most likely not support them, which will limit your target platform

> Why do the JDK developers leave undocumented properties in the openjdk
> implementation

Because it is implementation detail and might be subject to change. Once made public, it's hard to make change without affecting consumers of this code.